# Highcharts series.data not working for me

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use data from a csv to make a chart. I included the csv parser code, but you don't have to read it; I confirmed it's working correctly from console.log. arr[1] looks something like this:

```
[[1,2],
 [3,4],
 [5,7]]
```

I pass arr[1] to series.data (close to the bottom); however, I get a blank graph. I'm trying to get a simple (x,y) line graph. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: I pasted that 2D array from above into series.data and it made a graph...I think my parser code is running after my Highcharts code. Why is that/how do I fix that.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Stock Data - Highcharts</title>


            <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->       
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

            <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on DOM loaded -->
            <script>

            //CSV parser

                var arr = new Array();
                function successFunction(data) {

                    var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);

                    for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
                        var this_row = allRows[singleRow].split(',')
                        if (singleRow === 0) {
                            //start at the first yaxis column
                            for (var i = 1; i < this_row.length; i++) {
                                arr[i] = new Array();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            for (var i = 1; i < this_row.length; i++) {
                                var a = Number(this_row[0]);
                                var b = Number(this_row[i]);
                                var temp_arr = [a, b];
                                arr[i].push(temp_arr);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    console.log(arr[1])
                }
                var csv_name = "just-prices-sample.csv"
                $.ajax({
                  url: csv_name,
                  dataType: 'text',
                }).done(successFunction);

            //end of CSV parser

          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

              Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'line'
                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 1
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Stock Price'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Price (Dollars)'
                        }
                    },
                    series : [{
                        data: arr[1],
                        type: 'line'
                    }]
                });
            });

            </script>

        </head>
        <body>

            <!-- 3. Add the container -->
            <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>                
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that values in array are numbers? They might be strings, and if I remember correctly, they need to be numbers for charts.

Comment: They are numbers. You can see from within my else statement in my parser. I believe the problem is that the parser code is running after my Highcharts code. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because it's async. You should then make Highcharts.chart part in another function, place that ajax call inside DOmContentLoaded and call them both when ajax is done. .done (() => {successFunction(); chartsFunction()} )

Comment: I did what you said, but I get an error essentially saying successFunction's parameter, "data", isn't known. So I put "data" (not in quotes) between the parenthesis in the .done call and it says data isn't defined. I'm a total noob here and copy pasted in your .done function to the letter. Are you sure there isn't a syntax error there?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. .done((data) => { successFunction(data); chartsFunction(); }) Also, chartsFunctions you write yourself for your highcharts object

Comment: Perfect!! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Look like you don't get `arr` as you defind

here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/nageen/oxrL8fd2/

i have make it static because your CSV file not giving any data. you have to check why you not getting data from CSV file. i just want to show everything is good except you `arr[1]` because arr is getting data from CSV and if CSV don't give data then `arr` will empty and it not showing graph.

Comment: You just made data: [1,2,3,4,5]. I need to use data from my csv

Comment: Yes but as you can see define arr is not getting data so that chart is not showing, please check you why you not getting data from csv

Comment: once you get data correctly from csv file then definitely your chart will show

Comment: What do you mean by get data correctly? My parser works if that's what you mean; if you don't mean that, please elaborate as to how to get the data correctly.

Comment: you have to console.log(arr[1]) and it will get like that [1,2,3,4]. also check what data format pass to highchart.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer (thanks to askerovlab):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Stock Data - Highcharts</title>


        <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->       
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

        <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on DOM loaded -->
        <script>

        //CSV parser

            var arr = new Array();
            function successFunction(data) {

                var allRows = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);

                for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
                    var this_row = allRows[singleRow].split(',')
                    if (singleRow === 0) {
                        //start at the first yaxis column
                        for (var i = 1; i < this_row.length; i++) {
                            arr[i] = new Array();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        for (var i = 1; i < this_row.length; i++) {
                            var a = Number(this_row[0]);
                            var b = Number(this_row[i]);
                            var temp_arr = [a, b];
                            arr[i].push(temp_arr);
                        }
                    }
                }

                console.log(arr[1]);
            }


        //end of CSV parser


            function chartsFunction() {
              Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'line'
                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 1
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Stock Price'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        max: 25,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Price (Dollars)'
                        }
                    },
                    series : [{
                        data: arr[1],
                        type: 'line'
                    }]
                });
              }


      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          var csv_name = "just-prices-sample.csv"
            $.ajax({
              url: csv_name,
              dataType: 'text',
            }).done((data) => { successFunction(data); chartsFunction(); })
        });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- 3. Add the container -->
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>                
    </body>
</html>
```